# Can the following mysql query be rewritten in a simpler syntax?

Tags: mysql

I am very new to mysql and I have a rather complex query which I am sure can be shortened or optimized.

Is there a way not to repeat the `site = '{$site}'` condition every time?

Or not to repeat the first condition when I order the results by case?

Can this query can be rewritten in not so many word?

```
SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE

(site = '{$site}' AND (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%'))

OR 

(site = '{$site}' AND (desc1 LIKE '%new%' OR desc2 LIKE '%smok%'))

ORDER BY CASE 

    WHEN (site = '{$site}' AND (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%')) THEN 1 

    ELSE 2 END 

LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$table} 
WHERE
    site = '{$site}' 
    AND (
      id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%'
      OR desc1 LIKE '%new%' OR desc2 LIKE '%smok%'
    )
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%') THEN 1 
        ELSE 2 
   END 
LIMIT 50
```

`site = '{$site}'` is not required in the `order by` clause, since the `WHERE` clause filters out rows that don't meet the condition `site = '{$site}` - in other words all selected rows are from this site `{$site}`.

Comment: Ty, I'll test it, I believe the $site is required in the case statement... will test and come back

Comment: I think ordering may be rewritten to something like `order by (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%') desc`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably about as compressed as you'll get:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
site = 'site'
AND ((id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%')
 OR (desc1 LIKE '%new%' OR desc2 LIKE '%smok%')
)
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN (site = '{$site}' AND (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%')) THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 END 
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the first two conditions into one. However, I don't think you will be able to avoid the last "WHEN site = ..."

```
SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE

    site = '{$site}' AND ( (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%') 
    OR (desc1 LIKE '%new%' OR desc2 LIKE '%smok%') )

ORDER BY CASE 

    WHEN (site = '{$site}' AND (id LIKE '%bwm%' OR id LIKE '%merc%')) THEN 1 

    ELSE 2 END 

LIMIT 50
```

This is a pretty neat and simple statement anyway.